# Why do strings end up as unreadable in MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, web3js

Im using Node JS to create random ethereum accounts and I would like to store them in the mysql database (yeah I know it's bad but that's not the point).
Insertion goes without errors, but when I look at the inserted data it looks unrecognizeable.

I've tried changing collation into various encodings but nothing helped. Also, this: res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

CODE:

```
const newAcc = web3.eth.accounts.create();

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err || !newAcc) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

  var sql = 'INSERT INTO eth_accounts (addressEth, privateKeyEth) VALUES 
   ('+newAcc.address+', '+newAcc.privateKey+')';

  con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
  });

  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM eth_accounts';
  con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
 });
```

I've been using PHP so far and every time a string would look strange I would just slap *use utf 8* command on top and it would work.

This is the error message that I'm getting:

> ????J????m~?G?ȓ?L^ as address, ?]??n?A*j?[|??-hޏ?gx?_>?{?-?| as
>   key...

Comment: At the moment it's *utf8_unicode_ci*.

Comment: Shouldn't you have quotes around your strings? I.e. `var sql = "INSERT INTO eth_accounts (addressEth, privateKeyEth) VALUES ('" + newAcc.address + "', '" +  newAcc.privateKey + "')";`

Comment: But also, I think it's important to point out that you really shouldn't put  together SQL statements with string concatenation like this. Your particular use case is probably okay (assuming you trust web3.js), but you should really let your SQL library do the work of quoting and escaping strings for you.

Comment: You probably should use a node.js method that prevents SQL injection which coincidently handles random strings without error. If you also do XSS prevention mechanims when you display them that will also solve some forms of erroneous display.

Comment: @danblack SQL injection is probably irrelevant in this situation since his just just scraping with his server.

Comment: @Mile can you put a `console.log(sql);` before your first query and show us the results?  Not sure if the issue is with the query itself or the newAcc object.

Comment: @smarx Those quotes have solved the issue. Also, I escaped strings in this way: `var sql = 'INSERT INTO eth_accounts (addressEth, privateKeyEth) VALUES (?, ?)';

  con.query(sql, [newAcc.address, newAcc.privateKey], function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });`                                                                                                                            Would you say this is the correct way of inserting?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score 0):

Per comment discussion above, the solution was to use quotes around the strings:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO eth_accounts (addressEth, privateKeyEth) VALUES ('"
          + newAcc.address + "', '" + newAcc.privateKey + "')";
```